# Issue inApp firebase

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, in-app

I have an inApp that it's not showing on iOs (Android it's ok)... Any help with this?

I've tried differents events for showing but nothing it's working, don't know if it's something related with firebase or my events. :/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.